# Docker for an Angular-Java app : ports not exposed properly

Tags: java, angular, docker, maven, port

I am trying to dockerize a full-stack Java(Springboot)-Angular app. The Angular app is embedded in the application and makes REST calls to the Java app as GET localhost:8080/getSomeInfo. My Dockerfile is as

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8 AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/*.jar /usr/local/lib/app.jar
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /usr/local/lib/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/app.jar"]

FROM node:12.2.0
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY src/main/web/package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@10.1.2
COPY src/main/web /app
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

I build it as
docker build -t springio/myapp .

I need to expose both the angular port and the java port, so I run it as
docker run -p 9898:4200 -p 8080:8080 -t springio/myapp

I am able to bring up the web page, but it cannot reach out to the Java server (can't connect to 8080). How can this be fixed please?

I have tried putting 'EXPOSE 8080' in the dockerfile, but that did not work

Comment: Here the final image created is of node with your angular app, the spring build is left behind, it was an intermediary image.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put 2 applications in the same container. Although you can, it is considered a bad practise and it defeats the purpose of using containers.

I suggest having 2 Dockerfile: one for the back-end (java app) and one for the front-end (Angular app). Build each of them separately and start them independently.

For your specific problem I don't think the port is the problem, but is the Java app that is not even starting (it is actually not even present in the final image). Splitting the Dockerfile and starting the apps separately will fix your issue.

`EXPOSE` doesn't actually do anything. It is there to inform users of the Dockerfile which ports the application is listening on, so that they know which ports to map on the host.